# Difference Between Cleveland and Eastlake Manufactured King Super 20 Alto Saxopone

Tags: saxophone

What are the differences between a Cleveland manufactured Super 20 (specifically 60's) and an Eastlake manufactured alto Super 20 (specifically early/late 70s)?

A Cleveland alto seems to be selling for USD ~3500 while an Eastlake alto seems to be USD 2000- 2500.

Comment: Forwarded to a sax repair (and playing) expert; will report back.

Comment: The expert says: some play well and are worth it;  some play like crap. The price should reflect the quality of the individual item.